# Creating RPM using source file in current directory

Tags: rpm

I have a source file `program.py` I wish to package into an RPM.
I also have a .spec file in the same directory as `program.py`.

I tried doing this in the .spec file:

```
%prep
cp ./program.py $RPM_BUILD_DIR
```

But this does not work as `rpmbuild` does a `cd` before the `%prep` section:

```
% rpm build program.spec
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cp ./program.py /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
cp: cannot stat `./program.py': No such file or directory
```

Note that I cannot hardcode the path to the source `.py` file in the .spec file as it is under source control (git if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do for copying from the current directory:

```
Source:     %{expand:%%(pwd)}

%prep
# clean out old files
find . -mindepth 1 -delete
cp -af %{SOURCEURL0}/. .
```

Having rpmbuild automatically set the source URL to the current directory is simpler than using command line flags.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install mock
mock -r fedora-22-x86_64 --scm-enable --scm-option method=git \
  --scm-option package=your_package --scm-option git_get=set \
  --scm-option spec=your_package.spec --scm-option branch=master \
  --scm-option write_tar=True --scm-option \
  git_get='git clone git@git_ip_address:SCM_PKG.git SCM_PKG'
```

This will create tar.gz file from you git (using git-archive) and it will be named according Source0 tag.
In %prep section you will be changed to directory where will be this archive unpacked.

For more details see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock/Plugin/Scm

**Edit:**
If you do not want to do additional checkout, you just need to create tar.gz file yourself (git archive is your friend). And put it in spec as Source0

Then you do

```
%prep
%setup -q
```

This will unpack that tar.gz file and change into root of that unpacked tree and change to %name directory. More about %setup options can be found here:  http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html

Then you should be able to do:

```
%install
install -d %{buildroot}%{python3_sitelib}/program
cp -a program.py %{buildroot}%{python3_sitelib}/program/program.py
```

Note that there exist program "tito", which should easy those steps (creating archive, bumping version... ): https://github.com/dgoodwin/tito

You can see my old blog post where I go into more details:
http://miroslav.suchy.cz/blog/archives/2013/12/17/how_to_create_new_release_of_rpm_package_in_5_seconds/

Comment: I don't want to do a git checkout as part of the build process, since that is done already as part of the larger build process.

Comment: I altered my answer with other options without need of git checkout.